# Adding multiple audio track into a website

Tags: html

People who visit my site get irritated while hearing the same audio track playing in my website while it is loaded. I have added the audio track using:

```
<embed src="admin/<?php echo $audio_result_fetch['current_audio'];?>" autostart="true" loop="true" width="0" height="0">
</embed>
<noembed> <bgsound src="admin/<?php echo $audio_result_fetch['current_audio'];?>" loop="infinite">
```

And I'm used to change the tracks periodically.

But is there any possible way to add multiple audio tracks that may play repeatedly??

Comment: Maybe they get irritated because you auto start the audio? Anyway, have a look at [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) it should provide you with everything you need, including playlist functionality.

Comment: Oh and if you don't care about cross-browser support, the example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/33/) might work well for you.

Comment: Ya the audio starts automatically when the site is opened. And I don't want the user to choose the audio track. It is the customer requirement to do so. The admin have to set a playlist which is to be played while the site is opened.